# Regular Expression for XX + XX

Tags: c#, regex, textbox

Can anyone help me with the regex of this one:

AB + CD

I tried this formula [A-Z][A-Z] + [A-Z][A-Z] but it returns false match

Anyone?

Comment: Can you explain what is your goal pls?

Comment: @Misters: The OP is trying to match `AB + CD` using a regular expression.

Comment: i forgot that plus sign (+) is a special character, which only needs and escape character ( \ )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the `+`

```
[A-Z][A-Z] \+ [A-Z][A-Z]
```

Also would be better written as:

```
[A-Z]{2} \+ [A-Z]{2}
```

Comment: thanks, it's the correct one. i forgot that plus sign (+) is a special character, which only needs and escape character ( \ )

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://txt2re.com/, it is very easy to use and also spits out the code in required language (although it does come out over inflated and ugly, but easy enough to clean up). Example for your particular query below in C#.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string txt="AB + CD";

      string re1="([a-z])"; // Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 1
      string re2="([a-z])"; // Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 2
      string re3="(\\s+)";  // White Space 1
      string re4="(\\+)";   // Any Single Character 1
      string re5="(\\s+)";  // White Space 2
      string re6="([a-z])"; // Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 3
      string re7="([a-z])"; // Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 4

      Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String w1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String w2=m.Groups[2].ToString();
            String ws1=m.Groups[3].ToString();
            String c1=m.Groups[4].ToString();
            String ws2=m.Groups[5].ToString();
            String w3=m.Groups[6].ToString();
            String w4=m.Groups[7].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+w1.ToString()+")"+"("+w2.ToString()+")"+"("+ws1.ToString()+")"+"("+c1.ToString()+")"+"("+ws2.ToString()+")"+"("+w3.ToString()+")"+"("+w4.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```